# Writing Query statement with a String and a Date in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

Using an ADODB connection, I have an excel database where I store data, and I am trying to make a query in one of the sheets(db_Reports). Values for Lastname and Birthday are entered in textboxes (tb_Lastname & tb_bday, respectively) from a userform.

My problem is that the first two query statements work (commented in this case): one queries Lastname which gets a string, the other queries a date. Each of them works separately, but if I combine them since I need to query both name or date in the same search, it is giving me Type Mismatch; Runtime error 13. I have been searching anywhere but I can't figure out how can I make this work. I even tried to convert date into a string but still, it failed.

```vb
Private Sub SearchRecords_Click()

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection 
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset 
    Dim db_path As Variant

    db_path = "E:\DATABASE.xlsm"

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & db_path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;"";"

    Dim qry As String

    'qry = "Select [LastName], Format([Birthday], 'mmmm dd, yyyy') from [db_Reports$] where [LastName] = '" & tb_Lastname & "'"  'Working
    'qry = "Select [LastName], Format([Birthday], 'mmmm dd, yyyy') from [db_Reports$] where [Birthday] = '" & CStr(CLng(CDate(tb_bday))) & "'"  'Working
    qry = "Select [LastName], Format([Birthday], 'mmmm dd, yyyy') from [db_Reports$] where [LastName] = '" & tb_Lastname & "' or [Birthday] = '" & CStr(CLng(CDate(tb_bday))) & "'"  'Not Working - Type Mismatch; Runtime error 13'

    rst.Open qry, conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    rst.Close
    conn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Basically, how can you make a query for both a string and a date in one line?

I apologize for the long code line, the lingo I used, and even the formulation of the question as I am a self-taught newbie.

Comment: At which line does that error get thrown?

Comment: at line 15              qry = "Select [LastName], Format([Birthday], 'mmmm dd, yyyy') from [db_Reports$] where [LastName] = '" & tb_Lastname & "' or [Birthday] = '" & CStr(CLng(CDate(tb_bday))) & "'"  'Not Working - Type Mismatch; Runtime error 13'

Comment: And can you show us how `tb_Lastname` and `tb_birthday` get set?

Comment: I appreciate your question but I do not know what you mean by "get set." It must be wrong for me not to set it or I may have done something to it not knowing that I have "set it" already. I have been doing the same by not setting them up but it had worked before. Can you please expound what you mean by "get set"? To tell a bit more, those are the Names I assigned the textboxes.

Comment: Sure thing, what I mean is that there must be some code somewhere that looks like `tb_birthday = some_value`. What I'm thinking is that one of those items is not being set correctly which could cause the error. The mismatch error means a "type" error. Quick example, if your variable expects a number but you provide a string that cannot be converted to a number, then you will get this kind of error. By the way, don't worry that you're new to this stuff. We all were at some point.

Comment: I did not set them as their values will be provided by the entries in their respective textboxes. I was wondering why if they worked separately but not together. Can I make a query statement for both a string(Lastname) and a date together? Thx

Comment: I think I may have a workaround. Upon checking it seems that  '[Birthday] = '" & CStr(CLng(CDate(tb_bday)))' creates Type mismatch error if there is no value entered. I will just make an If-then Statement as a workaround. Unless you have a better idea. I don't know if I can answer my own question.

Comment: I think that is a good solution. You should be able to answer your own question. I forget if you need a certain amount of reputation points to do so. Nice job figuring it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that '[Birthday] = '" & CStr(CLng(CDate(tb_bday))) &' creates an error when no value is entered in the textbox, tb_bday. I cant explain why. As a workaround, I just created an if-then statement. I still would want to avoid using if-then if it can be coded in one line instead.

```
Private Sub SearchRecords_Click()

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection 
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset 
    Dim db_path As Variant

    db_path = "E:\DATABASE.xlsm"

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & db_path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;"";"

    Dim qry As String

    if tb_bday.value = ""  then 
        qry = "Select [LastName], Format([Birthday], 'mmmm dd, yyyy') from [db_Reports$] where [LastName] = '" & tb_Lastname & "'"  
    else 
        qry = "Select [LastName], Format([Birthday], 'mmmm dd, yyyy') from [db_Reports$] where where [LastName] = '" & tb_Lastname & "' or [Birthday] = '" & CStr(CLng(CDate(tb_bday))) & "'"
    end if 

    rst.Open qry, conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    rst.Close
    conn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: it errors because, `CDate(...)` [expects a valid date expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/type-conversion-functions) and an empty string isn't one.  If you want your users to run the query without a date, you can't avoid the check.  Note the correct check is `If tb_Name.Text = vbNullString Then` (`Null` and `""` (an  empty string) arn't the same thing).  Note: you'll still get an error if the user enters something that is not a recognisable date.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I did use "" instead of null in my code coz just like you warned me about, it made an error. Of course, you spot my error before i had a chance to edit it. But I appreciate you informing me that I cant avoid the check coz I have spent the weekend just to find that out. Also to avoid an unrecognizable date, I put up validation in the textbox. Thanks.